# Sylius Security: Login-form Google reCaptcha

Tags: symfony4, recaptcha, sylius

I'm trying to add ReCaptcha to Sylius Login Form, I have installed [stefandoorn/sylius-recaptcha-plugin](https://packagist.org/packages/stefandoorn/sylius-recaptcha-plugin) and followed all installation instructions, but it's not validating, the form is logged even when the captcha field is empty, no error is throwed.
I'm currently using Sylius v1.7

The view is working well and look like that:
[Login with captcha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54fz0.png)
I have extended SecurityLoginType and created an Extension:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Form\Extension;

use EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\Form\Type\EWZRecaptchaType;
use EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue as RecaptchaTrue;
use Sylius\Bundle\UiBundle\Form\Type\SecurityLoginType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class SecurityLoginTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->add('_recaptcha', EWZRecaptchaType::class, [
            'mapped' => false,
            'constraints' => [
                new RecaptchaTrue(),
            ],
            'attr' => [
                'defer' => true,
                'async' => true,
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public static function getExtendedTypes(): iterable
    {
        return [SecurityLoginType::class];
    }
}
```

And register the extension on **config/services.yml**

```
app.form.extension.type.security_login:
        class: App\Form\Extension\SecurityLoginTypeExtension
        tags:
            - { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Sylius\Bundle\UiBundle\Form\Type\SecurityLoginType }
```

And override the login tempate in **SyliusUiBundle/Security/_login.html.twig**

```
...
{% form_theme form '@EWZRecaptcha/Form/ewz_recaptcha_widget.html.twig' %}

{{ form_errors(form._recaptcha) }}
{{ form_widget(form._recaptcha, { 'attr': {
    'options' : {
        'theme': 'light',
        'type': 'image',
        'size': 'normal'
    },
} }) }}
...
```

Any suggestions about it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle docs how to use the recaptcha validator. Make sure it's enabled first lol. Also make sure you're using the same validation group in the login form, usually in Sylius it's `sylius`, but you didn't set any validation group AFAICT.

Comment: emix, the EWZRecaptchaBundle Bundle is enabled and it's working well on contact form and register form, but curiously on login form it didn't work. I have tried setting the **sylius** as validation group but the result was the same, i think the problem could be on SecurityLoginType and the way that it's used by the framework, because it didn't validate any constraints.

Comment: It sounds to me like it has to do with how Symfony internally validates it. I'm not able to help you right now, but in case you find out, would you like to submit a PR to the plugin repository so we can include it for other users as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a way to do that, as I'm using FOS bundle, symfony internally does not validate the login form itself and then we need to catch the login form before it's processed.
I have added an event event subscriber on `KernelEvents::REQUEST` with priority 9  because class `Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener` (responsible for registering the events for symfony firewall) has priority 8.

Here is the code, it's explained by itself:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Sylius\Bundle\UiBundle\Form\Type\SecurityLoginType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;

class LoginSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onLogin', 9]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param RequestEvent $event
     */
    public function onLogin(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        // Check for login route name
        if ('sylius_shop_login_check' !== $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route')) {
            return;
        }

        // Get the login form
        $loginForm = $this->formFactory->createNamed(null, SecurityLoginType::class);

        $loginForm->handleRequest($event->getRequest());

        if ($loginForm->isSubmitted() && !$loginForm->isValid()) {
            // And here code when the form is invalid
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to say thanks to the community. This post was very useful for me:
[Add listener before login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45173869/add-listener-before-login/45189763#45189763)